# Remove unwanted characters in excel

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I'm trying to compile some categories for an upload and we have excessive arrows.

> Animals > Pet Supplies > Bird Supplies >  >  >  >
>
> Animals > Pet Supplies > Bird Supplies > Bird Cages & Stands >  >  >
>
> Animals > Pet Supplies > Bird Supplies > Bird Food >  >  >
>
> Animals > Pet Supplies > Bird Supplies > Bird Ladders & Perches >  >
>
> > 
>
> Animals > Pet Supplies > Bird Supplies > Bird Toys >  >  >
>
> Animals > Pet Supplies > Bird Supplies > Bird Treats >  >  >
>
> Animals > Pet Supplies > Cat Supplies >  >  >  >
>
> Animals > Pet Supplies > Cat Supplies > Cat Beds >  >  >

In excel how can we remove an excessive arrows so they look like this

> Animals > Pet Supplies > Bird Supplies
>
> Animals > Pet Supplies > Bird Supplies > Bird Cages & Stands
>
> Animals > Pet Supplies > Bird Supplies > Bird Food
>
> Animals > Pet Supplies > Bird Supplies > Bird Ladders & Perches
>
> Animals > Pet Supplies > Bird Supplies > Bird Toys    Animals > Pet
>   Supplies > Bird Supplies > Bird Treats    Animals > Pet Supplies > Cat
>   Supplies
>
> Animals > Pet Supplies > Cat Supplies > Cat Beds

We've just concatenated a bunch of rows to make them up but were left with excess arrows in some rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've said you have all of the text in one cell in a column (after concatentation) so if there are extra `>` after the text try this:

```
=LEFT(A1,(LEN(A1)-1))
```

Assuming the text is in column A.

Answer (score 0):

Quick & dirty: Find / replace "> >" with ">" until the file is clean for the upload.